# Ссылка на VK группу в подвале сайта

Tags: поддержка, предложение, дизайн, vk-группа

Есть ли возможность добавить ссылку на [VK группу](https://vk.com/stackoverflow) в подвале сайта или в движке это всё захардкожено?

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможность есть всегда, но инвесторам это не нужно. Не думаю, что сделают какую-то возможность кастомизации кроме перевода. К тому же ссылки на компанию в целом, а не на конкретный сайт.

Comment: @älёxölüt по тому, как они на сайтах сети старательно выпиливают кастомные дизайны, не удивлён.

Comment: А linkedin можно вообще у нас убрать. Всё равно без vpn не работает.